# Changing Views in Fragments

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

In My app, i use an altered Example of the ViewPagerIndicator, which launches 5 Fragments. so far all works well, but the fragments do have to change their View (completly new layout) for other purposes. how do i do that? a Fragment doesn't have a function SetContentView like activities do. so is there a way to update the view or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Fragment.getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) to get the root view of the Fragment. On that `View`, call `removeAllViews()`. Then build your new views and add them to the view you got from `getView()`.

**Edit**

I never used Mono for Android before, but looking at the documentation; I suggest you put the inflated View from inflater.Inflate in a private member of your Fragment. Later on, when needed, you can use that reference to edit your layout.

Comment: if you look [>here<](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.App.Fragment%2fM) you can see, there is nothing like getView for Fragments

Comment: Uh oh, I missed you're using monodroid. Sorry about that. Would be nice though if you'd mention that in the description of your question next time.

Comment: well, i tried to put another view into re (another inflated layout) but it didn't work, even calling Force and rquest layout out of curiosity didn't do anything.